# Create and configure multiple ColdFusion instances in load balanced environment using scripts

Tags: coldfusion

I'm wondering if there is a method to create and configure multiple ColdFusion instances from the script after the initial silent installation? Note: I have already figured out how to silently install and update default ColdFusion instance (And including multiple instances if I can create them using scripts)

What I'm tying to do is to completely script multiple ColdFusion instances installation (instances with their own Apache websites and configuration files) and configuration ( Ex. deploy settings using .car file) for use in the rapid deployment using docker in the load balanced environment. If this is not possible any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You might want to try Stackoverflow. Make sure to include a disclaimer that no one responded on serverfault.